# How does one add KeyBindings to an AWT Frame?

Tags: java, swing, awt, key-bindings

Over the past few months, I have been using Java.Awt.Frame to create a screen and keyListeners for keyboard input. However, my program has become to complicated for keylisteners, so I recently decided to use KeyBinds instead. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to add them to the AWT frame. I attempted to create a JPanel and add that to the frame(using add()), however, this did not appear to do anything. Any input would be appreciated; please refer to my code if you need to.

```
import java.awt.*;    
import BreezyGUI.*;
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Action;



public class fltsm extends GBFrame implements KeyListener
{
    private static int fps = 0; 
    private static int score = 0;
    private final int TIMER_DELAY = 100; //milliseconds
    private static final int KEY_DOWN = 40; // KEYCODES
    private static final int KEY_UP = 38;
    private static final int KEY_RIGHT = 39;
    private static final int KEY_LEFT = 37;
    private static final int KEY_SPACE = 32;
    private static final int KEY_0 = 48;
    private static final int KEY_1 = 49;
    private static final int KEY_2 = 50;
    private static final int KEY_3 = 51;
    private static final int KEY_4 = 52;
    private static final int KEY_5 = 53;
    private static final int KEY_6 = 54;
    private static final int KEY_ENTER = 10;
    private static final int SCREEN_LENGTH = 1000;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static String keyWord;
    private static String commandString = ""; // When the user types in alphabetic keys, they are added to this String and matched to a list if executable commands.
    boolean timerStarted = false;
    boolean keyListenerAdded = false;
    boolean calledByEvent = true;
    boolean KeyPressed = false;
    boolean drawFPS = false;
    int kCode = 0;
    KeyEvent event = null; // helps clear out unwanted keyListeners(see object Listener class below)

    private static ArrayList<Missile> miss = new ArrayList<Missile>();
    private static ArrayList<Missile> Co = new ArrayList<Missile>(); 
    World w1 = new World(SCREEN_LENGTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    Plane flyer = new Plane();
    Timer t;



public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if (drawFPS == true)
        fps++;

    if (Plane.getPlanes().indexOf(flyer) == - 1) // Until I find a better solution...
        {    
            Plane.addPlane(flyer);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            add(panel);
            panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1", "doSomething");  
            panel.getActionMap().put("doSomething", new anAction());

        }  

     addKeyListener (this); 
     Plane.processPlanes(g);
     PlaneMissile.processMissiles(g, w1, calledByEvent);
     BotMissile.processMissiles(g, w1, calledByEvent, flyer);
     TrackingBot.processBots(g, w1, flyer);
     DeathLaser.processLasers(g, flyer);
     ScanningLaser.processLasers(g, flyer);
     EMP.processEMPs(g, flyer);
     Wall.processWalls(g, w1, flyer);

     drawStatBox(g, flyer);
}      


public static void main (String[ ] args)
{
         //normalizeGraphics();
         Frame frm = new fltsm( );
         frm.setSize (SCREEN_LENGTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
         frm.setTitle("Flight Simulator");
         frm.setVisible(true); 

}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
{    
     kCode = event.getKeyCode();
     keyWord = String.valueOf(kCode);

     if (timerStarted == false)
     {
         ObjectListener x = new ObjectListener ();
         t = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, x);
         t.start(); 
         timerStarted = true;
     }   

 }   
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event ) 
{
    removeKeyListener(this);  // removes unwanted keyListeners (this method cannot be called in the ObjectListener class)
}

public void keyReleased ( KeyEvent event) 
{
}

public KeyEvent getEvent ()
{
    return event;
}


 class ObjectListener implements ActionListener // Called to process objects that move on the screen
{                                        // regardless of whether a key is pressed.
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       keyTyped(getEvent());  // This line clears out the unwanted keylisteners, which would otherwise build up everytime the paint() method is called.
       repaint(); 
       calledByEvent = false;
   }     
}    

class an implements AbstractAction // Called to process objects that move on the screen
{                                        // regardless of whether a key is pressed.
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       TrackingBot.botMania();
   }     
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final int KEY_0 = 48;
```

Don't use magic values. Nobody knows what 48 is. I'm assuming KEY_0 is representing KeyEvent.VK_0, so use that variable and don't make up your own.

> I recently decided to use KeyBinds instead. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to add them to the AWT frame

You can't add binding to a Frame. Key Bindings are for Swing components only. Don't mix AWT and Swing. Just use a JFrame with a JPanel, then you can use Key Bindings easily.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

Don't override the paint() method of a top level container. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the panel to the frame.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
add(panel);
```

Don't create and add components to a frame in a painting method. A painting method should only do painting.

```
panel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1", "doSomething");  
panel.getActionMap().put("doSomething", new anAction());
```

The default InputMap will only support KeyBindings with the component has focus. By default a JPanel doesn't have focus. The easier approach is to use one of the other InputMaps. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to find out more about these other InputMaps.

Comment: Thank you, I eliminated the magic numbers(they were unnecessary with keybindings anyway), I moved my Jpanel to the newly-created fltsm constructor and I used pnl.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW as a parameter for getInputMap().

Comment: The focus was the main problem.